# Accessing data from Database View from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view, postgresql-9.1

I have created a view according to this blog:
http://viget.com/extend/rails-nested-has-many-through-with-sql-views

The migration was successful. My view name is the same as the blog (groupby_entries).

I can see that view was successfully created and data is accessible from it when I do a select * on it from my DB UI.

I would like to use this as a table from now on only to retrieve the data (group by queries).
But, when I try to access the data from my rails console it throws an error:

1.9.3p194 :002 > GroupbyEntry.find(:all)
NameError: uninitialized constant GroupbyEntry

Am I missing on adding something somewhere? Kindly let me know.. I tried Groupby_entry.find(:all) as well.. But it gives out the same error.

Thanks,

Comment: To add on.. I have slightly modified the way of creating the view, I use

class CreateGroupEntriesView < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
   create_view_sql = "CREATE VIEW group_entries as select * from ..."   
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(create_view_sql)
   end
   
where create_view_sql is my raw sql to create a view.

Similarly it goes for drop view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494779/connecting-a-rails-model-to-a-database-view/12345025#12345025

This is what I was missing.. Thanks to the genius! :)