# "No attribute named `name` exists" error when using a sql database view instead of a table for my model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Heres is the output:

```
(rdb:5) Morphology::MatrixView
Morphology::MatrixView(Table doesn\'t exist)

(rdb:5) Morphology::MatrixView.table_name
"morphology_matrix_view"

(rdb:4) Morphology::MatrixView.all.first
#<Morphology::MatrixView name: "anex", description: nil, copied_from: nil, created_by: "", created_at: "2012-12-14 18:40:51", updated_by: "", updated_at: "2012-12-14 18:40:51", id: 7, matrix_id: 7, copied_from_id: nil, project_id: 81>

(rdb:4) Morphology::MatrixView.all.first.name
"anex"

(rdb:4) Morphology::MatrixView.where(:name => 'anex')
INTERNAL ERROR!!! No attribute named `name` exists for table `morphology_matrix_view`

(rdb:12) Morphology::MatrixView.where("name = ?", "anex")
[#<Morphology::MatrixView name: "anex", description: nil, copied_from: nil, created_by: "", created_at: "2012-12-14 18:40:51", updated_by: "", updated_at: "2012-12-14 18:40:51", id: 7, matrix_id: 7, copied_from_id: nil, project_id: 81>]
```

I have a model that represents a database view (postgres).

Basically `model.where(:attribute => "string")` throws an error,

but `model.where("attribute = ?", "string")` does not.

Not sure how to proceed here, any suggestions *(using activerecord 3.0)*?

Comment: I suspect that `name` may be reserved, either by Rails or by the underlying RDBMS. Try changing it.

Comment: Print the generated queries in the log, please.  To turn on ActiveRecord logging do `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Comment: You have run the migrations, right?

Comment: Yes migrations.

log from failed https://gist.github.com/4320589

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW 
put a debugger inside https://github.com/ernie/meta_where/blob/master/lib/meta_where/utility.rb in attribute_from_column_and_table method

`/home/cdell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/meta_where-1.0.4/lib/meta_where/utility.rb:15
case column
(rdb:2) column
:name
(rdb:2) table
#<Arel::Table:0xc45b300 @name="morphology_matrix_view", @engine=ActiveRecord::Base, @columns=nil, @aliases=[], @table_alias=nil, @primary_key=nil>
(rdb:2) table[column]
nil
`

Comment: OK I swear I googled and searched stackoverflow for a long time on Friday and this morning but low and behold [here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494779/connecting-a-rails-model-to-a-database-view)